# Am I forced to use the .cgi extension?

Tags: c++, cgi, cgi-bin

I am going to build CGI web application and start learning that technology. I'd like to use C++. So I started my local server and put a simple script in my `cgi-bin` folder, compiled it with `g++ test.cpp -o app` (using Mac OS X) and tried to run it with: `localhost/cgi-bin/app`. And it worked.

But reading on the web I keep seeing examples where scripts are compiled(?) as `.cgi` files. Am I forced to do the same? What's the difference?

Comment: Take a look at fastcgi as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify .cgi extension.
That said, please note that the choice to use CGI and C++ for developing interactive web applications is very unusual at this point.  People pretty much stopped doing it this way some time in the 90s.
Not to say that there is never a reason to do it.
But be warned.

Comment: I know it's unusual but I like to give it a try. I'm not doing anything serious, I just want to try to survive and create a website with it, just for experience. But I might like it...

Comment: @dan04 Why?  Not being sarcastic.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: Short answer: It's too low-level of a language with too small of a standard library (compared to .NET, Python, etc.)

Comment: @dan04 Isn't it the fastest?  If latency is the top concern and you don't want to pay for .net or are in lamp, why not go that way?

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy latency is very unlikely to be the top concern in the world of CGI.  In the world of LAMP "P" doesn't stand for C++, it stands for Perl, PHP or Python.  The other reason is security.

Comment: @MK. Are those the only reasons?  Not trying to bait.  I need max speed and minimum $ for my site, and this http://blog.famzah.net/2010/07/01/cpp-vs-python-vs-perl-vs-php-performance-benchmark/ says C++ fully optimized is 30x faster than PHP, exactly what I need.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy how do you know you need 40x faster than PHP?  Minimum $ is definitely not C++.  C++ development is slower and developers are more expensive.

Comment: @MK. My site is heavily dependent upon dynamic pagination.  Ping is ~50ms, and the rest of the latency is ~100ms which makes sense since I get ~10ms on my local 8gb,2.3ghz wampserver where my VPS is about 1gb, 0.29ghz (my allocation).  I'm a one man show, so I'd rather spend the time writing faster AJAX with C++ than spend 6x what I am now to get the same processing times as my laptop lol.  I definitely agree that dev is slower, oh is it slower especially when you're trying to learn the language ;)).  150ms kills the effect.  If I can get total lag ~ ping lag, I'm a happy camper.